# create N number of Edittext on button click

Tags: android, android-edittext, textchanged

I want to create Edittext one below one on a button click.So i tried the following code.

```
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;
    int k = -1;
    int flag;
    int ss=0;
    ArrayList<String> applnserverinstnos = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText textView[] = new EditText[100];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                k++;

                flag=k;
                final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
                lparams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
                textView[flag] = new EditText(AddEditBoxActivity.this);
                textView[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                textView[flag].setId(flag);
                applnserverinstnos.add(flag,Integer.toString(flag));
                textView[flag].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             String c = s.toString(); // read Content
                             applnserverinstnos.add(flag,c);
                             System.out.println("insno       "+applnserverinstnos.get(flag));
                        }
                    });

                mLayout.addView(textView[flag]);


            }
        });
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0;i<=k;i++) 
                {
                System.out.println("applserver   "+i+".."+applnserverinstnos.get(i));
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

This creates the edittext one below one.I tried creating 3 edittext.But when i try to enter texts into edit text it throws  following error.

```
06-13 12:44:47.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
```

Please help me to find it.
Thank You.

**EDIT**

after adding `applnserverinstnos.add(flag,Integer.toString(flag));` it is not throwing error but the text changed in edittext one is not storing in position one instead  it is storing in last position

Comment: updated questing with exception

Comment: First, provide logcat error traces.. Second, learn to debug.. third, tell us where exactly you are getting error i.e. on which part of code...

Comment: not an answer to your question, but naming an edittext[] "textview" is pretty confusing

Comment: i thing you have to generate edittext with layouinflator and for getting value from edittext you can use getTag and setTag method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found solution which is very simple and small.Now the following code creates N number of edittexts  and also get the value from those edittexts created.

```
 private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;
    int k = -1;
    int flag;
    int ss=0;
    ArrayList<String> applnserverinstnos = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static EditText textView[] = new EditText[100];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                k++;
                flag=k;
                final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
                lparams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
                textView[flag] = new EditText(AddEditBoxActivity.this);
                textView[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                textView[flag].setId(flag);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mLayout.addView(textView[flag]);


            }
        });

        Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0;i<=k;i++) 
                {
                System.out.println("edit values"+ss+"......"+ textView[i].getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Just my thought:
I think after you clicked edittext, function `afterTextChanged` is called. Currently variable `flag` is 3. However size of `applnserverinstnos` is still 0. So `applnserverinstnos.add(flag,c);` will cause the error.

Comment: I recommend you to use hashmap instead of arraylist.

Comment: The reason of the new problem is because flag is always the last index of the array. applnserverinstnos.add(flag,c); here flag should be replaced with the id of the corresponding edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your own TextView custom object that has a specific watcher attached to it, something like below.

```
class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(android.content.Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

}
```

you can, of course customize it to add your own text watcher etc. all that is required might be a lil bit of analysis. Let me know if anything